# find a field in a table via a value of another table field value using EF and Linq

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I have tow Models like these:

```
public class ServiceModel
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string GroupName { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }

}
```

and:

```
 public class ShopServiceModel
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int ShopId { get; set; }
    public virtual int ServiceId { get; set; }
    public virtual int Time { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual ServiceModel  Service { get; set; }
}
```

and using Entity framework makes me these tables in database:

Service Table:

[image: Service Table]

ShopService Table:

[image: ShopService Table]

However,I want to use Linq query and take ServiceId field value from ShopService table and find service name in Serivce table I mean the Name field value in Service table,So how can I do that and is my models correct to do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to do a join in Linq?

Comment: That's what your navigation property Service is for. var myShopService = context.ShopServiceModel.Include(s => s.Service).FirstOrDefault(s => s.ServiceId == valueToFind);   Then you can get to the name with "myShopService.Service.Name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is correct.  To get the ShopService (and corresponding service name), you would just do something like this:

```
var shopService=db.ShopServices
  .Include(s=>s.Service)
  .Where(ss=>ss.Id=1);

Console.WriteLine("Shop Service:{0} has a name of {1} and took {2} minutes",
  shopService.Id,shopService.Service.Name,ShopService.Time);
```

or to list them all:

```
var shopServices=db.ShopServices
  .Include(s=>s.Service);
foreach(var shopService in shopServices)
{    
  Console.WriteLine("Shop Service:{0} has a name of {1} and took {2} minutes",
    shopService.Id,shopService.Service.Name,ShopService.Time);
}
```

or use a projection to pull out the fields you want:

```
var ss=db.ShopServices.Select(s=>new {Id=s.Id,Name=s.Service.Name,Time=s.Time});
foreach(var s in ss)
{    
  Console.WriteLine("Shop Service:{0} has a name of {1} and took {2} minutes",
    s.Id,s.Name,s.Time);
}
```